# Use dynamic name as param Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple params and when I do a get request I want to have just a function that takes the name of the params its value.

The problem is, the params is as I defined, and not the value.

```
this.debounce("search_fullname", 5);

debounce(searchField, value) {
  this.$router.push({
    query: {
     ...this.$route.query,
     searchField: value 
    }
  })
 }
```

In the url I get `/?searchField=5` instead of `/?search_fullname=5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.debounce("search_fullname", 5);

debounce(searchField, value) {
  this.$router.push({
    query: {
      ...this.$route.query,
      [searchField]: value <--- Dynamic key in js object
    }
  })
}
```

*You shall get `/?search_fullname=5` instead of `/?searchField=5` in the url.*